# Java function in class is not working

Tags: java, class, intellij-idea

Apologies in advance if this is a really simple fix. But I'm new to the world of Java and trying to create a simple script for giggles.

I have created a simple class in which I am calling my Pet class. It containers the simple blueprint of the class, and a function which I wish to be able to call in my Main class.

```
import java.awt.*;

public class Pet {

    String petType;
    Color petColor;
    String petSound;

    public Pet(String inputType, Color inputColor, String inputSound){
        this.petType = inputType;
        this.petColor = inputColor;
        this.petSound = inputSound;
    }

    public void petSpeak(String Pet.petType){
        System.out.println(Pet.petSound + "!!");
    }
}
```

However, I don't think I'm doing it right/missing something. Because the IDE I'm using (IntelliJ) is putting red squiggly lines under `Pet.petType`.

My Main class contains the following code:

```
Pet Rex = new Pet("Dog", Color.BLACK, "Woof!");
Pet Thumper = new Pet("Rabbit", Color.WHITE, "...");
Pet Jim = new Pet("Budgie", Color.YELLOW, "Cheep Cheep!");

System.out.println(petSpeak(Rex.petSound));
```

What I am trying to do is that when `petSpeak` is called (with a petType as an argument). That pets sound is printed out to the user.

Any help in getting this to work would be great!

Comment: Hover your mouse over the red squiggly lines and read what's wrong

Comment: In your method definition, and more specifically in your input a type and a name of the variable is expected. So there, you just need a name like public void speak(String type). You try to use the member variable petType. You could also rename the method to speak(). The pet prefix is redundant.

Comment: Btw. there is no need for an argument to `petSpeak`. It is a method to be called on an object like so: `Rex.petSpeak()`.

Comment: Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `public void petSpeak(String Pet.petType)` to `public void petSpeak()` and

`System.out.println(petSpeak(Rex.petSound));` to `Rex.petSpeak();`

Basically you don't need argument in `void petSpeak()` because object Rex already has that value witch is assigned here `Pet Rex = new Pet("Dog", Color.BLACK, "Woof!");` and you call methods from classes by typing `objectName.methodName`